# Use VBS to copy multiple text files to multiple locations

Tags: vbscript

I would like to copy config files from one location and overwrite them to another location. Below is my example script, can anyone help me get this working please?

```
strFileToCopy = "C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\Strat App 4 point to Pan 3.txt" 
strFolder = "C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\test\" 


Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
objFSO.CopyFile strFileToCopy, strFolder, OverwriteExisting  
Else
Wscript.Echo "Target Folder does not exist."
End If

strFileToCopy = "C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\Stat App 4 point to Pan 3.txt" 
strFolder = "C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\test 2\" 


Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
objFSO.CopyFile strFileToCopy, strFolder, OverwriteExisting  
Else
Wscript.Echo "Target Folder does not exist."
End If

Wscript.Echo "App 4 is now pointing to Pan 3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit unclear question. However, in next **commented** code snippet are described basic improvements:

```
''' disable error handling; show error and stop instead
On Error GoTo 0

Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strFileToCopy = "C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\Strat App 4 point to Pan 3.txt" 
strFolder = "C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\test\" 

If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
    objFSO.CopyFile strFileToCopy, strFolder, OverwriteExisting  
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Target Folder does not exist."
End If

strFileToCopy = "C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\Stat App 4 point to Pan 3.txt" 
strFolder = "C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\test 2\" 

''' you cannot redefine a constant value
''' Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE
''' you need not redefine a variable to the same value
''' Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
    objFSO.CopyFile strFileToCopy, strFolder, OverwriteExisting  
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Target Folder does not exist."
End If

Wscript.Echo "App 4 is now pointing to Pan 3"
```